# Assigning Today() on a DateOnlyType field on InfoPath 2010

Tags: infopath, date-time

I made an InfoPath 2010 form using a SharePoint list template. The SharePoint list has a **ReceivedDate** field of **DateOnlyType** which I would like to set using the today() or now() on a "Set a field's" value rule.

Upon running the rule on a button click I get an error "Only date or date and time is allowed". How can I set this field *without* changing it from DateOnlyType to a TextType field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the the today() formula, it will return that error you are talking about. For SharePoint fields you have to use now().

Comment: Both today() and now() didn't work when I tested it in the office SharePoint server. At home, the now() function works. I'll need to test this again on other SharePoint test servers at the office.

Comment: Thats strange, let me know if its some other issue :)

Comment: It's working now when I tested it again. Hopefully, I will not encounter that problem again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the value 'Today()' or 'now()' in infopath using substring function to the date format you require in the list.